# Electron app isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, electron

I wanted to convert quite simple web app to a desktop app with electron. But there is one big problem. The app, that I want to convert is here: **dinoz.mobi/shelter-editor**

So as you can see there is a page that tells us to load a file.

When I converted it to desktop app, it looks like this: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpLTL.jpg)

This is my package.json file:

`{
  "name"    : "Editor",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}`

And main.js file:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1366, height: 768})
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false
    }
  win.show()

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/shelter.html`)


  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

And here is link to app's github page: https://github.com/MobileSam/shelter-editor

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, repaired by adding this script  `<script>window.jQuery = window.$ = module.exports</script>`
after a `<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`